# How to add isLeaf and children to NSManagedObjects to use with a NSTreeController?

Tags: swift, macos, core-data, nstreecontroller

I am trying to use `NSManagedObject`s with an `NSTreeController` and `NSOutlineView` in my `macOS` app.

I have a two level data in the outline view: `Project` and `Item`, both are `NSManagedObject`s set up in my model.

In my storyboard, I added this:

[image]

[image]

And I added this in my code:

```swift
extension Project {
    @objc var isLeaf: Bool {
        return false
    }
    
    @objc var childCount: Int {
        return items?.count ?? 0
    }
    
    @objc var children: [Item] {
        return items?.allObjects as! [Item]
    }
}

extension Item {
    @objc var isLeaf: Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    @objc var childCount: Int {
        return 0
    }
    
    @objc var children: [NSManagedObject] {
        return []
    }
}
```

When I run the app, I get the following error:

`Thread 1: "[<MyApp.ProjectBrowserViewController 0x600001580820> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key isLeaf."`

It doesn't say which class but that error shows up twice, so I am guessing once for `Project`, and one for `Item`.

What am I missing here, how do I fix this?  Will gladly add more info if needed.

Comment: That error message says you are trying to use `isLeaf` on an instance of `ProjectBrowserViewController`. Check your tree view configuration, you seem to be asking for values on the wrong thing.

Comment: What is bound to what? Tip: Add `-NSBindingDebugLogLevel 1` to the “Arguments to be passed at launch” list.

Comment: Thank you both, I will need to do some debugging. In the meantime, are the settings in the screenshots and the code in my question correct?

Comment: Note that the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/using_key-value_observing_in_swift) say "Mark properties that you want to observe through key-value observing with both the `@objc` attribute **and** the `dynamic` modifier. " (emphasis mine)

Comment: Adding `dynamic` did not solve this. I'll keep digging.

Comment: Any bindings in the Referenced Bindings section of the Connections Inspector of the `ProjectBrowserViewController`? What is the error with `-NSBindingDebugLogLevel 1`?

Comment: @willeke Yes - I had a lingering connection for `content` to the Tree Controller. Removing that made the crash go away. The error did not change with the debug flag.